# Generate uml diagram from Visual Studio C # Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uml

I have a C # solution in Visual Studio 2017. It is a solution with several child projects, at least 6, and within these projects there is a hierarchy of folders and subfolders and classes.
I need a free and preferably open source program so that I can generate the class diagram of every solution from the source code already deployed.
I know there is a native Visual Studio solution that makes this code transformation into diagrams, but in this case, the generated format is a .cd, which I could not import into Visual Paradigm. Also, the generated diagram is for projects only, individually and I need a way to generate it for the entire solution.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe have a look at doxygen, it can generate uml diagrams for a project as part of its documentation.

Comment: Is there one that focuses only on generating the class diagram? This software I used but could not diagnose my architecture. If I don't point to the folder where the classes are, it just does nothing and brings me a blank document. Already the native of Visual studio can already, however the format it generates was not recognized by Visual Paradigm. If there was a way to export this Visual Studio native to a different format, like an .xml, that would be a big help.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about e.g. the blank documents. With some settings you can get already som documentation from doxygen. generate a base Doxyfile (`doxygen -g`  in the main source directory) and have in this file a look at (a.o.) `EXTRACT_...`, `HAVE_DOT`, `CLASS_...`